# Apply value to ID's that are the same R

Tags: r, if-statement, unique-key

Using the below dataset as an example:

```
  id flag
1  1    Y
2  1     
3  1     
4  2     
5  2    Y
6  3    Y
```

Reproducible example:

```
df <- data.frame(id=factor(c(1,1,1,2,2,3)), flag=c('Y','','','','Y','Y'))
```

If there exists a flag = Y for any ID then I want all that ID to have the flag "Y" so the above example would look as follows:

```
  id flag
1  1    Y
2  1    Y
3  1    Y
4  2    Y
5  2    Y
6  3    Y
```

Comment: why does 3 loose its Y-flag???

Comment: Sorry that was a typo, I've corrected it now.

Comment: In the df you provide 3 doesn't have a Y flag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solution using `dplyr` is

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(flag_new = ifelse(any(flag == "Y"), "Y", as.character(flag)))

# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   id [3]
  id    flag  flag_new
  <fct> <fct> <chr>   
1 1     Y     Y       
2 1     ""    Y       
3 1     ""    Y       
4 2     ""    Y       
5 2     Y     Y       
6 3     ""    ""
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to preserve the groups without `'Y'`, you have to use a different method.

```
df <- data.frame(id=factor(c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3)), flag=c('Y','','','','Y','Z', 'G', ''))
#   id flag
# 1  1    Y
# 2  1     
# 3  1     
# 4  2     
# 5  2    Y
# 6  3    Z
# 7  3    G
# 8  3     

# Thanks @akrun, for rewriting to avoid using "do" function
df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(flag_new = if(any(flag == "Y")) "Y" else as.character(flag))

#   id    flag  flag_new
#   <fct> <fct> <chr>   
# 1 1     Y     Y       
# 2 1     ""    Y       
# 3 1     ""    Y       
# 4 2     ""    Y       
# 5 2     Y     Y       
# 6 3     Z     Z       
# 7 3     G     G       
# 8 3     ""    ""
```

Accepted answer:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(flag_new = ifelse(any(flag == "Y"), "Y", as.character(flag)))
#   id    flag  flag_new
#   <fct> <fct> <chr>   
# 1 1     Y     Y       
# 2 1     ""    Y       
# 3 1     ""    Y       
# 4 2     ""    Y       
# 5 2     Y     Y       
# 6 3     Z     Z       
# 7 3     G     Z       
# 8 3     ""    Z
```

Answer (score 1):

Or using `data.table`, convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`), grouped by 'id', get the row ids (`.I`) where there is any "Y" `%in%` the 'flag' column, use that as `i` and assign (`:=`) the 'flag' elements of that 'id' to "Y"

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[df[, .I["Y" %in% flag], id]$V1, flag := "Y"][]
#   id flag
#1:  1    Y
#2:  1    Y
#3:  1    Y
#4:  2    Y
#5:  2    Y
#6:  3
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(id=factor(c(1,1,1,2,2,3)), flag=c('Y','','','','Y',''))
```

Comment: alternative `setDT(df)[id %in% df[, any(flag == "Y"), id][V1 == TRUE, id], flag := "Y"]`